# DC.js and ReactJS - zoomable bar charts - .focus([]) not working

Tags: reactjs, dc.js

There is a very good example of a zoomable bar chart on the DC.js examples website:

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/focus-ordinal-bar.html

Has anyone been able to get a similar thing working on React JS? I get an error when .focus([]) is called, or it merely deselects the bars and doesn't affect the focus. I've a workaround using a DIV mask but it's messy.

Comment: Are you using [react-dc-js](https://github.com/dc-js/react-dc-js) or another framework for integrating dc.js with React?